# Recordtype does not work as a drop-in replacement to namedtuple collection

Tags: python, python-unittest, namedtuple, recordtype

I'm pretty new to Python so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. Originally I had a class that was subclassed by collections.namedtouple. I was my understanding that recordtype can be used as a drop-in replacement for someone who wants a mutable namedtuple. However when i went from this code:

```
class SplitResultsContainer(collections.namedtuple('SplitResultsContainer', _URI_COMPONENTS)):
```

to this code:

```
class SplitResultsContainer(recordtype.recordtype('SplitResultsContainer', _URI_COMPONENTS, default=None)):
```

one of my tests failed:

```
self.assertEquals(splituri('foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose'), ('foo', 'example.com:8042', '/over/there', 'name=ferret', 'nose'))
AssertionError: SplitResultsContainer(scheme=foo, authority=example.com:8042, path=/over/there, query=name=ferret, fragment=nose) != ('foo', 'example.com:8042', '/over/there', 'name=ferret', 'nose')
```

I am creating a URI parser to teach myself Python. Any help regarding why the tuple does not match recordtype in my test would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: ok so it works if I do this: tuple(splituri('foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose')) but I don't really want to do that. I would rather compare a recordtype to recordtype instead of forcing recordtype to tuple. Thanks again.

Comment: Why are you subclassing?  Do you understand what the AssertionError means?  Did you write the unittest?  Is there anything relevant in the rest of the `SplitResultsContainer` class that we might need to see?

Comment: If you solved the problem and the question is no longer valid, can you delete it?